# How to add object to collection inside another collection in MongoDB using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I know how to add object to collection in MongoDB using Node.js, for example:

```
router.post('/addProduct', function (req, res) {
    Partner.findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: req.body.partnerId }, { $push: { "products": { name: req.body.dataProduct.name } } }, { safe: true }, function (err, response) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.json(response);
    });
});
```

but what if in product will be another table? How can I simply add object there?

Let's say this is my schema:

```
var partnerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    products: [
        {
            name: String,
            campaignList: [
                {
                    name: String,
                    type: String,
                    startDate: Date,
                    endDate: Date,
                    paymentMethod: String,
                    partnerPayout: Number,
                    ourPayout: Number
                }
            ]
        }]
});
```

ID in each `partner` and `product` are default `._id` eg. `partner._id` and `product._id`. That's why aren't in schema above. However I sending them from FrontEnd to BackEnd as a `req.parameter` - normally thing but i wanted to say it for sure :)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would bet to define the Schema & Model for the campaign on its own, and add it to the Partner by reference using the `_id`

```
var partnerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    products: [
        {
            name: String,
            campaignList: [
                { type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref : 'campaignModel' }
            ]
        }]
});
var campaignSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  type: String,
  startDate: Date,
  endDate: Date,
  paymentMethod: String,
  partnerPayout: Number,
  ourPayout: Number
});
var campaignModel = mongoose.model('campaignModel', campaignSchema);
var partnerModel = mongoose.model('partnerSchema', partnerSchema);
```

A good practice is to look for times where you're trying nest semi-complex data, or objects with more than two or three keys, and extract them into their own collection. Not only does it make it easier to search for those documents, it makes it easier to use them in conjunction with other objects.

Be sure to call `.populate()` during your query so that MongoDB knows to nest the documents from the other collections, otherwise, you'll just have an array of `ObjectId`.

Answer (score 0):

First match the required products array position. You can confirm this by testing a simple find like:

```
Partner.find({_id: req.body.partnerId), 'products.name': req.body.dataProduct.name }, { 'products.$': 1})
```

Use the positional $ operator to push the new object into the array in the matched product element:

```
Partner.update({_id: req.body.partnerId), 'products.name': req.body.dataProduct.name }, { $push: { 'products.$.campaignList': { name: 'new campaign' }}})
```

Reference https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

Comment: I tested this outside of Mongoose directly through Robomongo and it updated as expected. Perhaps there's some other detail preventing this working? Perhaps an issue with the req.body.partnerId or req.body.dataProduct.name references?

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
router.post('/addProduct', function (req, res) {
        Partner.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.body.partnerId }, { $push: { "products": { name: req.body.dataProduct.name, $push: {"campaignList": {name: req.body.name}} } } }, { safe: true }, function (err, response) {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.json(response);
        });
    });
```

i hope it helps you

Comment: This code will add NEW `product` instead add `campaignList` to already existing